# Determining the coefficients of divisors under a blowup of smooth varieties along smooth subvarieties.

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $ \pi: Y \rightarrow X $ blowup of a smooth variety along a smooth subvariety, with exceptional divisor $ E. $ Then $$ \operatorname{Pic}Y \cong \pi^{*}\operatorname{Pic}X \oplus \mathbb{Z}E $$

(can I find a proof of this fact in most books? )

A challenge for me is how to determine the coefficients of these divisors in explicit cases. I would really appreciate seeing an example of how this works.

Edit: After further reflection, I have identified the clearest way to ask my question, but first a bit of background:

Consider a log variety $ (V,B), $ and let $ \varphi: V' \rightarrow V $ be birational morphism, and $ E \subset V' $ a prime divisor. Now in general for a divisor $ D $ on $ V, $ I think we can apply a valuation $ \operatorname{ord}_{E}, $ to obtain some multiplicity $ \nu_{E}(D) \in \mathbb{Z}_{\geq 0} $ of an effective divisor $ D $ with respect to $ E. $ If $ \varepsilon $ is the set of exceptional divisors of the birational morphism $ \varphi, $ and $ D' $ the strict transform of $ D $ on $ V', $ then $$ \varphi^{*}D = D' + \sum_{E \in \varepsilon} \nu_{E}(D)E. $$ In the case of the canonical class $ K_{V'} $ we get 
$$ K_{V'} = \varphi^{*}K_{V} + \sum_{E \in \varepsilon} a(E)E, $$ where the number $ a(E) $ is called the discrepancy of the geometric valuation $ E, $ and is independent of the model $ V'. $

My question is, what is this multiplicity $ \nu_{E}(D) $ and how do we compute it explicitly? I realise that I do not really understand what these coefficients mean.

Comment: You have two statements here which are somewhat unconnected: your title and the last line seem unconnected to the statement about Picard groups. Can you make what you're hoping to do here more clear?

Comment: @KReiser  I have edited the question in a way that may be more informative. I apologise if it was too vague before. I myself wasn't able to see what it was that I was struggling with

Answer (score 3):

If $X$ is projective, then it comes from blowup formula on cohomology. (See Voisin's *Hodge Theory and Complex Algebraic Geometry, vol I*, Theorem 7.31.)

Denote $Z$ the blowup center of $X$, then $E$ is a projective bundle over $Z$ with rank $r-1$, where $r=\operatorname{codim}_XZ$. There is an isomorphism of Hodge structure 
$$H^2(X,\mathbb Z)\oplus H^0(Z,\mathbb Z)\xrightarrow{\pi^*+\theta} H^2(Y,\mathbb Z)\tag{1}\label{1}$$
where $\theta$ is composite of $\pi_{|E}^*:H^0(Z,\mathbb Z)\to H^0(E,\mathbb Z)$ and Gysin homomorphism $H^0(E,\mathbb Z)\to H^2(Y,\mathbb Z)$.

Now, Lefschetz $(1,1)$-theorem says that for smooth projective variety $W$, $$H^{1,1}(W,\mathbb C)\cap H^2(W,\mathbb Z)=\operatorname{Pic}(W),$$
together with $(\ref{1})$, it gives you the blowup formula for Picard group as you wrote.

As for examples, work out blowup a point on $\mathbb P^2$, blowup a smooth curve in $\mathbb P^3$ would be helpful.